# How to pass argument into php that executed in python?

Tags: python

I need to pass an argument into my php code that executed in python

```
import subprocess
def php(code):
    p = subprocess.Popen(["php","-r", code],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.communicate() #returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata)
    if out[1] != b'': raise Exception(out[1].decode('UTF-8'))
    return out[0].decode('UTF-8')
val = str(1234)
code = """ \
function my_encoder($in){
    $out = base_convert($in,16,36);
return ($out);}

print(my_encoder('"""+{val}+"""'));
"""
print(php(code))
```

I don't know how to input val in php code as argument of my_encoder function.

Comment: What exactly is your question: How to transfer data into PHP (as command line argument or maybe through standard input) or how to transfer data to an external program called from within Python? If it is a PHP question it should be tagged with "PHP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `{`, `}` if not as part of Python's f-string as this makes invalid syntax. So just drop these braces:

```
print(my_encoder('"""+val+"""'));
"""
```